# Как сделать блочный шаблон в laravel

Tags: laravel

В Laravel шаблон каждой страницы прописан в полной форме `<html><head>...`

Что нужно мне: единая точка входа, только в ней должна быть прописана полная структура, а содержимое элемента `body` будет подгружаться в зависимости от страницы.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Ну так сделайте общий шаблон, и наследуйтесь от него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документация по шаблонам: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-a-layout

Так же данный раздел из русской документации:

> При определении дочернего представления используйте Blade-директиву
>   @extends для указания макета, который должен быть «унаследован»
>   дочерним представлением. Представления, которые наследуют макет Blade,
>   могут внедрять содержимое в секции макета с помощью директив @section.
>   Запомните, как видно из приведённого выше примера, содержимое этих
>   секций будет отображено в макете при помощи @yield:
>
> @extends('layouts.app')
>
> @section('title', 'Page Title')
>
> @section('sidebar')
>       @parent
>
> ```
> <p>Это дополнение к основной боковой панели.</p> @endsection
> ```
>
> @section('content')
>
> Это содержимое тела страницы.
>
> @endsection
>
> В этом примере секция sidebar использует директиву @parent для дополнения (а не
>   перезаписи) содержимого к боковой панели макета. Директива @parent
>   будет заменена содержимым макета при отрисовке представления.

За наследование на странице отвечает @extends('тут шаблон body')

В самом же боди (лайауте) надо определить секцию @yield('content')

Comment: еще тупой вопросик, как определить запрашиваемую страницу?     Route::get('/', function () {}); на подобии этого только для блэйда

Comment: Что значит определить запрашиваемую страницу?
Если текущую страницу, то 
request()->route()->getName() - имя текущего роута.
Другие методы для текущего роута  request()->route() https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getName